# $_Post undefined variable var_dump

Tags: php, forms

Hey I'm creating my first php form and really struggling with what I'm doing wrong here;

this is the form:

```
               <form method="post" action="includes/contact-process.php">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                    
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">

                </form>
```

and this is the contact-process.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_Post);

?>
```

and this is what it keeps returning: 
**Notice:** Undefined variable: _Post in \includes\contact-process.php on line 3
NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be [**$_POST**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), not `$_Post` :

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is case sensitive, $_POST is not same as $_Post so try

```
var_dump($_POST);
```